# How to update second value of map using iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function in which it checks for the characters and number of times it is repeated in a string.

It is stored as (for example)string is "hello" [h]=>1 [e]=>1 [l]=>2 [o]=1

Whenever a letter occurs more than once I need to update it.

I tried using

```
it->second = it->second+1;
```

But it doesn't works
How can I do that?

Full code is

```
int fn(string a) {
  map<char,int> mymap;
   for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
   {
       std::map<char, int>::iterator it = mymap.find(i);
       if(it!=mymap.end())
       {
            //say i need to update occurrence from 1 to 2 or 2 to 3...
           it->second = it->second+1;//(how can i do that)
       }
       else
       mymap.insert(pair<char,int>(a[i],1));
   }
   std::map<char,int>::iterator i;
   for(i=mymap.begin();i!=mymap.end();i++)
   {
       cout<<i->first<<i->second;
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. It works fine when I try to compile the example you provided.

Comment: @juanchopanza  provides the elegant solution. BTW: the problem of your solution is just a typo: `mymap.find(i)` ->  `mymap.find(a[i])`

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/TeHBNT)

Comment: @StephanLechner silly mistake. Thanks!!! It Worked

Comment: @Muthu In the future, it would be helpful to specify what "But it doesn't works" means. I incorrectly assumed you meant a compilation error. It's also my bad for supposing and not asking for specifications.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux oh its just a logical error.  In future i'll specify it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need all that code. You can just say

```
for (auto c : a) mymap[c]++;
```

This works because map's `operator[]` inserts a zero initialized element when one doesn't exist for a given key.

Comment: I was just about to comment when you added the range for.  +1 for that.

Comment: But i need to find a particular character mymap.find(i). If that occurs i need to increment

Comment: @Muthu If the element `a[i]` is not found, it's initialized to 0, so the loop body increments it to 1. This is exactly what you do in your `else`'s body.

Comment: @Muthu No I don't think you need to actually do that.